# nutritional profile of grilled sunflower heads (not just seeds)

Tags: vegetables, nutrient-composition

I've been seeing recipes that recommend grilling the whole head of the sunflower, including the heart and the semi-mature seeds. I'm curious if there's a good way to estimate the nutritional profile here - I have not found any sources that directly answer the question and I would be surprised if one exists since it's an apparently uncommon practice.

Some near-misses:

- The nutritional profile for mature sunflower seeds is probably pretty close. But almost all sources strongly recommend against eating the shells. The shells for semi-mature sunflower seeds are actually rather soft and chewy so I think that in this application I aught to factor them in
- The nutritional profile for artichoke heart seems to be the closest proxy for the fleshy part of the sunflower behind the seeds. Artichoke and Sunflowers are both in the family Asteraceae so they may share some stuff in common